# Subset of nodes such that all nodes of a graph are adjacent

Tags: algorithms, graphs

We have been given a graph $G$, we need to find a subset of nodes $S$ such that each node of the graph is in $S$ or is adjacent to a node from $S$. Additionally, the elements of the subset $S$ should not be adjacent to each other neither should they share a common neighbour node.

This is an example of the given problem:
In the given graph, the subset $S = $ {2, 4} is a valid solution as $3$ and $5$ are adjacent to 2 while $1$ and $6$ are adjacent to $4$. Further, $2$ and $4$ are not adjacent neither do they share a common neighbour.

The subset $S = $ {4, 5} is NOT valid as $4$ and $5$ have a common neighbour $1$.
[image]

I have been looking for an efficient way to do this; my attempt at an algorithm gives an exponential time complexity.

Any hints are appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd start pondering *distance* and *cut*s.

Comment: @greybeard Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Out of my turf here, but sure I can: needing all nodes covered exactly once, you need nodes at a pairwise distance of three. Within a single connected component of $G$, it may lead to a useful heuristic to consider the/a *diameter*. Pondering cuts got me nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an [exact cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) problem, so you could use standard algorithms for exact cover; or you could use a SAT solver.

Answer (score 2):

In the literature, such a subset is called a *perfect code*.

As it is NP-complete to determine if a given graph has a perfect code, even on some very restricted inputs, your exponential-time algorithm is probably about as good as it gets.